# Text breaks after using the function. Not able to translate the text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `getResourceText('')`, which takes a key as a parameter. This function gives me a translation of the required text when invoked.

```
setFilterName = (isFilterChanged, buttonId, filterName) => {
    switch (filterName.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        case 'price':
            filterName = 'Price';
            break;
        case 'types':
            filterName = 'Car Type';
            break;
        case 'company':
            filterName = 'Brand';
            break;
        case 'airport':
            filterName = 'Airport';
            break;
        case 'city':
            filterName = 'City';
            break;
        case 'capacity':
            filterName = 'Capacity';
            break;
        case 'more':
            filterName = 'More';
            break;
        case 'extras':
            filterName = 'Extras';
            break;
        default:
    }

    if (isFilterChanged) {
        return (<button id={buttonId} type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary filter dropdown-toggle select" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">{getResourceText(filterName)}</button>);
    }
    else {
        return (<button id={buttonId} type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary filter dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{getResourceText(filterName)}</button>);
    }
}
```

In the piece of code given above, when I use the `getResourceText()` function, the text does get translated but it removes another text for which the code is given below. The `Exclude:` does not show up on the filter bar once I apply `getResourceText` over the filters.

```js
let excludeded = typeFilter[0].data.filter(i => i.ischecked == false);
if (excludeded != undefined && excludeded.length > 0) {
    let count = excludeded.length - 1;
    filterName = "Exclude: " + excludeded[0].name;
    if (count > 0) {
        filterName = filterName + " +" + count;
    }
```

Can someone look into this? I am stuck, can't move ahead.

Comment: pls let me know if u nee more info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the text gets translated your are passing filtername which have "Exclude: "+ + excludeded[0].name to the getResourceText function, if you want the exclude to show up you need to change your code like this :

```
 filterName = "Exclude: " + getResourceText(excludeded[0].name);
```

and in the buttons pass filtername

Comment: My question is when i pass the getResourceText over  filtername which is mentioned above in the first piece of code ,i am not doing anything with the Exclude:  The Exlcude text  is not showing up on the filters.  In the last few lines of the first peice of code i have shared  i pass the getResourceText over the filtername,i have created keys in my resource file similar to the name of these filters.The values of keys get passed here.

Comment: when does the second piece of code get called, is it the getResourceText function or what ?